# Using a package to deploy a change removed field tracking on custom field

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, standard-objects, field-history, deployment-error

One of our engineers deployed a change to Salesforce using the package system - namely a new field on the Lead object.

However, a field that was part of the same package on the account object: CSM Assigned (CSM_Assigned__c) had its field history tracking turned off automatically as part of the same deployment.

This field needs to be tracked at all times for numerous reasons.

How do we ensure any future changes to the package won't remove field history tracking again?